# MySQL - Does the READ UNCOMMITED isolation level use locks?

Tags: mysql, isolation-level, locks

So I am trying to understand more about the isolation levels and I read that the `READ UNCOMMITED` isolation level allows dirty readings which may lead to non-consistent readings. I also read that the

> `SELECT` statements are performed in a nonlocking fashion

So my question is, does this type of isolation uses locks for other statements? For example, if I use the `INSERT INTO` statement does it acquire locks?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: FYI if you are trying to solve a specific performance/locking problem (or generic database question like this one), I recommend asking directly about the root problem identified on https://dba.stackexchange.com/ .

There are a couple of uses for isolation levels however for `READ UNCOMMITED` it I suspect was something that was easy to implement in the server code rather than something based on a strong user requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Locks are still needed to ensure data transactions are atomic.

Also locks ensure that elements like auto_increments values only exist once.